# LIKE ANY Statement for SELECT Result Set

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Just as the `IN` operator allows you to specify multiple values in a `WHERE` clause, `LIKE ANY` / `LIKE ALL` can do the same for Wildcard queries in SnowSQL.

However, in ANSI SQL the `IN` operator also allows you to filter on the *result set* of a `SELECT` statement.

Is Snowflake able to execute the following without UDFs:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE ANY (SELECT STATEMENT)
```

EDIT:
Additional Context of an example query of this -

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT '%' || TABLE_NAME || '%' as TABLE_FOR_LIKE_ANY
FROM "MY_DATABASE"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."TABLES"
WHERE TABLE_NAME ILIKE ANY ('%FOO%', '%BAR%')
)

select *
from
"SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY"
where QUERY_TEXT ilike any (select TABLE_FOR_LIKE_ANY from CTE)
limit 100
```

Returns the following error:

> Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

EDIT2: Summary is `ILIKE` actually *DOESN'T* behave like `LIKE` for whatever reason in this scenario.

Comment: What's the meaning for `column_name(s)`?

Comment: In my answer below I fixed the added query above. The secret was to do `like` instead of `ilike` to support subqueries with multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes".

Did you try it?

```sql
WITH strings AS (SELECT $1 s FROM VALUES('%a%'), ('%b%'), ('%s%'))

SELECT column_name
FROM (SELECT 'bbb' column_name)
WHERE column_name LIKE ANY (SELECT s FROM strings);
```

---

Update:

- Query above fixed, as per Simon's comment.
- Updated query from the question fixed too, the trick is to do a `like` instead of an `ilike`:

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT '%' || TABLE_NAME || '%' as TABLE_FOR_LIKE_ANY
FROM "TEMP"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."TABLES"
WHERE TABLE_NAME ILIKE ANY ('%FOO%', '%BAR%')
)

select *
from
"SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY"
where QUERY_TEXT like any (select TABLE_FOR_LIKE_ANY from CTE)
limit 100;
```

Comment: Hi Felipe, I added an example query using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA as an example scenario. I also received an additional error.

Comment: the CTE select should be `SELECT $1 s FROM VALUES('%a%'), ('%b%'), ('%s%')` currently it's just one row with three values, of which you only select the first.

Comment: Duh!! My mistake, thanks @SimeonPilgrim. I also fixed the poster additional question by changing `ilike` to `like`.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, as it most directly answer the question I posed, but Simeon's is also very informative. It's strange that `ILIKE` doesn't behave the same as `LIKE` today. Moreover to Simeon's point it is actually exciting to consider `LIKE` as an option in a `JOIN`, which until I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 2):

As Felipe noted 'it works' BUT it can sometime give you the error "unsupported correlated subquery" but it is a corolated sub-query.

If small row based databases, doing lookups per row is simple/optimal, but on a big database like snowflake the optimal way is not so obvious. But you can flip any sub-query into a JOIN.

Thus

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE column_x IN (SELECT column_y FROM table_b)
```

can be:

```
SELECT column
FROM table
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT coulmn_y FROM table_b) ON table.column_x = coulmn_y
```

but now you might have some there are multiple column_z things errors. Alias's help here.

```
SELECT a.column
FROM table AS a
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT coulmn_y FROM table_b) AS b ON a.column_x = b.coulmn_y
```

now this can be in of itself not optimal when table_b is huge, but then you might know how to push some filters down into that sub-select, but this is the nature of how to structure the work.

[Update]
So this is Felipe's code with works, with both data and match strings push into CTE's

```
WITH match AS (
  SELECT '%' || $1 || '%' as mmm FROM VALUES ('aa'),('ab'),('ba')
), data AS (
  SELECT $1 as ddd  FROM VALUES ('caa'),('cba'),('cbc')
)
SELECT d.ddd
FROM data AS d
WHERE d.ddd LIKE ANY (SELECT mmm FROM match);
```

Which can be written as a JOIN like so:

```
WITH match AS (
  select '%' || $1 || '%' as mmm from values ('aa'),('ab'),('ba')
), data AS (
  select $1 as ddd  from values ('caa'),('cba'),('cbc')
)
SELECT d.ddd, m.mmm
FROM data AS d
JOIN match AS m 
    ON d.ddd LIKE m.mmm;
```

But if you have multiple match rows that match the data, you will get multiple output rows, this can be removed via QUALIFY, but the one below is unstable:

```
WITH match AS (
  select '%' || $1 || '%' as mmm from values ('aa'),('ab'),('ba'),('ba')
), data AS (
  select $1 as ddd  from values ('caa'),('cba'),('cbc')
)
SELECT d.ddd, m.mmm
FROM data AS d
JOIN match AS m 
    ON d.ddd LIKE m.mmm
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by d.ddd ORDER BY true) = 1;
```

where this one uses a sequence to also pick the "lowest" match:

```
WITH match AS (
  select '%' || $1 || '%' as mmm, seq8() as seq from values ('aa'),('ab'),('ba'),('ba')
), data AS (
  select $1 as ddd  from values ('caa'),('cba'),('cbc')
)
SELECT d.ddd, m.mmm
FROM data AS d
JOIN match AS m 
    ON d.ddd LIKE m.mmm
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by d.ddd ORDER BY seq) = 1;
```

Comment: I think the issue with approaching this as a `JOIN` is for this scenario I was searching for substrings in a larger strings. `JOIN`s imply equivalency, when my scenario simply isn't looking for exact matches, thus the need for a `LIKE ANY` Wildcard ex. `('%FOO%, '%BAR%')`. I updated the thread, I am sorry if it was not initially clear. Pretty neat SQL all the same though!